# global and local planners don't update calculated trajectory

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've set up a system comprising of:

- A laser scanner (Hokuyo URG-04LX)
- Remote computer connected to laser scanner running `roscore`, `hokuyo_node` and `laser_scan_matcher`
- A local computer running `gmapping` and `rviz`

and am trying to make `move_base` run on top of it all on the local machine. I went through [Robot Setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup), [Navigation Tuning Guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide), [Using rviz with Navigation Stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack) and all related questions here. It seems my basic setup is already mostly correct, but there is still something missing as neither **global** nor **local** planners update calculated trajectory on robot pose change.

My setup is mostly as described in [Robot Setup Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup),  i.e.:

**`costmap_common_params.yaml`**:

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
robot_radius: 0.1
inflation_radius: 0.3

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: /laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

**`global_costmap_params.yaml`**:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true
```

**`local_costmap_params.yaml`**:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 2.0
  height: 2.0
  resolution: 0.05
```

**`base_local_planner_params.yaml`**:

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:

  max_vel_x: 0.1 #m/s
  min_vel_x: 0.0
  escape_vel: -0.1
  max_rotational_vel: 0.1 #rad/s
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.0

  y_vels: [-0.1, -0.0, 0.0, 0.1]

  acc_lim_th: 1.0
  acc_lim_x: 1.0 #m/s2
  acc_lim_y: 1.0

  holonomic_robot: true
```

**`move_base.launch`**:

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

When I select a goal using `rviz` local and global trajectories get nicely drawn, but they don't change when I carry the "robot" around, only when new goal is being set. Besides, all I'm getting on /cmd_vel topic is the below output (so it would cause a real robot spin around endlessly).

```
linear: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -0.05
---
```

Both localization and odometry work as desired. Is there anything missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12475/global-and-local-planners-don%27t-update-calculated-trajectory/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-12-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-12-29**:
You shouldn't need Gazebo to verify that your navigation configs are working - Stage will work just fine for that purpose and is a lot easier to setup than Gazebo (unless you already have models and such done). Stage won't be a completely accurate sim, but it's enough to verify your configs function

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-29**:
Hmm. it actually looks like min_vel_x is being used as "typical" output value on /cmd_vel. Changing min_vel_x = 0.1 causes move_base to publish linear: x: 0.1, instead of 0, hence working. Considering what it says here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner this doesn't seem correct, or is it?

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-28**:
I haven't tried setting Gazebo up. Odometry works fine, gets published in /odom frame (but not as topic, is it necessary?), SLAM works ok too. Can low (but positive) max. velocities affect the outcome? - I'll try out changing them.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-12-28**:
Also, can you recreate this trouble in simulation?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-12-28**:
Just curious, but are your max velocities really that low?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-28**:
Odometry calculates when you carry the robot around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to publish your odometry on the /odom topic (or whatever you remap it as) as well as via tf.

`base_local_planner` subscribes to /odom to get it's velocity information. Not publishing it will cause `base_local_planner` to always output something near the min velocities (which is why the output changed when you changed your min vels), since it never receives feedback that the base has started moving, so it can't accelerate past the min velocity.

I'm a bit surprised that it didn't output something at least slightly greater than the set min_vel, since your acceleration is pretty high (compared to your min and max vels). Then again, I'm not 100% how `base_local_planner` treats not receiving /odom updates at all, but I know for certain it won't work correctly without them. I'm a little surprised you don't get any kind of warning for something like "no odom updates in the last N secs" or something... if this does turn out to be the problem, you should file a bug report against `base_local_planner` to throw a warning if no odom is received for some amount of time.

EDIT: Here's the relevant callback from the base_local_planner source, trajectory_planner_ros.cpp

```
341   void TrajectoryPlannerROS::odomCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg){
342     //we assume that the odometry is published in the frame of the base
343     boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(odom_lock_);
344     base_odom_.twist.twist.linear.x = msg->twist.twist.linear.x;
345     base_odom_.twist.twist.linear.y = msg->twist.twist.linear.y;
346     base_odom_.twist.twist.angular.z = msg->twist.twist.angular.z;
347     ROS_DEBUG("In the odometry callback with velocity values: (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f)",
348         base_odom_.twist.twist.linear.x, base_odom_.twist.twist.linear.y, base_odom_.twist.twist.angular.z);
349   }
```

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-12-30**:
Just set the linear x and y twist and the rotational z twist. These should be in "base_link" frame - base_local_planner doesn't do anything to convert twists into the base frame that it needs them in. I've updated my answer to include the relevant callback from base_local_planner's C++.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-30**:
Besides, do you know which exactly variables of the many provided in nav_msgs/Odometry does base_local_planner really need? Does it need both twist and pose, or just twist? Does it make any use of covariances, if given?

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-30**:
OK, thanks, I'll try it out as soon as I get a nav_msgs/Odometry message. At the moment all I have is a geometry_msgs/Pose2D from laser_scan_matcher. I'm not getting any warnings from move_base about missing subscriptions (nor from roswtf).